# Чтение данных из COM порта C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, serial, embedded

Написал программу на микроконтроллере которая в порт посылает данные(4 константных значения типа int) через функцию sprintf, sprintf переводит интовое число в строку. Строка состоит из байт символов ascii которые отсылает usart.

```
printf("+------- Pakage sending --------+");
sprintf(altitude,"alt: %d", ALT);

/* Send data to USART; */
timerDelayMs(300);
send_Uart_str(altitude);
send_Uart(NEW_LINE);
/* и тд. */
```

Открываю терминал и получаю следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> NEW_LINE - это символ каретки  в ASCII = 13;

На стороне ПК мне необходимо каждую строку записывать в отдельный буфер или переменные. Вот не могу понять как по каретке разделить. Набросал примитивное консольное приложение. Пока читаю по событию все содержимое из порта, но при рендеринге в консоли то же проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя при отладке в мониторе данные приходят нормальные, не битые.
Собственно класс порта:

```
 public class CustomSerialPort : SerialPort
{

    public event DataRecievedEventHandler DataChanged;
    public delegate void DataRecievedEventHandler(object sender, string package);

    public CustomSerialPort(string port)
        : base()
    {
        //base.PortName = COM1;
        base.BaudRate = 38400;
        base.DataBits = 8;
        base.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        base.Parity = Parity.None;
        base.ReadTimeout = 300;

        base.DataReceived += CustomSerialPort_DataReceived; ;
    }

    public void Open(string portName)
    {
        if (base.IsOpen)
        {
            base.Close();
        }
        base.PortName = portName;
        base.Open();
    }

    private void CustomSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var port = (SerialPort) sender;
        try
        {
            DataChanged?.Invoke(sender, port.ReadExisting());
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Основная программа:

```
 class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var port = new CustomSerialPort("COM3");
        port.Open("COM3");

        port.DataChanged += Port_DataChanged;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Port_DataChanged(object sender, string package)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(package);
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема со странным выводом в данном случае связана с символом `'\r'`, он же `NEWLINE` в рассматриваемом коде (что, кстати, запутывает, потому что обычно перенос строки — это всё-таки `10`, а не `13`).

Когда `'\r'` выводится в консоль — это переносит курсор в начало текущей строки. Поэтому в некоторых строчках вывода программы мы наблюдаем наложение нескольких строк из пакета, и они выглядят странно, как `?888d: 1337`.

Шагом к исправлению проблемы будет замена `Console.WriteLine(package)` на `Console.WriteLine(package.Replace("\r", "\n"))`. А ещё лучше на `Console.Write(package.Replace("\r", "\n"))`, чтобы пакеты перестали иногда разрубаться в середине строки.

Comment: Благодарю! Это решило проблему!

Answer (score 2):

Принятые данные нужно складывать в одну строку - буфер.
Когда в буфере появился CR (NEW_LINE) - скопировать всё до него и вывести в нужном формате.
Удалить начало буфера, включая CR

P.S.   `DataChanged?.Invoke(` обеспечивает синхронизацию обработчика события, которое выполняется в отдельном потоке, и `Port_DataChanged`?

Comment: Насчет синхронизации не уверен. Я пробрасываю событие DataChanged из класса сервиса в основную программу. Может и в этом причина.

Comment: Я делал в этом ключе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590945/how-to-display-the-data-read-in-datareceived-event-handler-of-serialport Возможно, спецы по шарпу что-то более современное подскажут